# MySql Returns Wrong Ordering Result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

[image]

Well, When I execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users order by rp_bought desc limit 5
```

I get no errors but, The `username`, `Raed` is in the last place as `Raed` Has the Most `Rp_Bought` (`1300`)

Im Wondering Why is this Problem Occurring.

Comment: what is the data type of `rp_bought` ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid rp_bought varchar(255) latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ for your next question.

Comment: @kapa I have an sql database and sqlfiddle is like anther database, Why should I test it again?

Comment: @user3356613 You set it up, and we don't have to ask questions, we can easily debug. Your image does not really give any information about your table, we can only guess. Also, why do you use varchar to store a number (and wonder why problem is occurring)?

Comment: because im here to learn not to annoy people around.

Comment: @user3356613 No need to take it personal, just thought you have any special reason to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would occur if `rp_bought` were stored as a string rather than as a number.  In MySQL you can easily fix this by adding 0:

```
order by rp_bought + 0 desc
```

The `+ 0` is an easy way to convert from a string to a number (with no additional errors occurring).

Comment: it Worked, Thanks Man I also saw this solution when I was reading a couple of Articles but, I added + 0 to the Mysql Query not the php script, I added it into the php and it worked very well ;)